# Offline To Do List Web Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have very heavy restrictions on what I can and cannot use or access on my work computer. I'd like to create a very basic but effective persistent To Do list to assist with my day-to-day task tracking. I'm looking to do this with the following tools:

1. HTML
2. JavaScript/jQuery
3. Text files

I do not have access to a web server. I'd like to make a local HTML file that I can run in my browser, and the To Do tasks would be stored in a text file which lives in a directory shared on our network. I do not want to use HTML5 localstorage as I would not have access to my To Do list if I work from one of the other computers on the network.

Is this possible? What is my best plan of attack here? Can I code my tasks as js objects and serialize them into a string to store in the text file? I apologize if that doesn't make sense; I modify code chunks found using google - I'm not a trained programmer.

Thank you!

EDIT:

Based on early feedback, it seems like this is not possible. If I went the HTML5 localStorage route, is there a way I can ensure I never go over the 5MB cap? Perhaps a function which deletes the bottom of the array as its running out of space?

Comment: Imho, not really possible as this would be a HUGE security issue.

Comment: Javascript does not work with files, it cannot read or write in file , so if you don't even want to use local storage, there are not other places to store your tasks .

Comment: Why you don't want to use a backend programming language?

Comment: Can you install `nodejs` and `npm`?

Comment: Writing to the file would be the hardest part. You would need either a) Some backend code on the shared server that you could send data to save to the Todo file, or b) Installing some backend on every computer you plan to use (sounds hard). Reading the file is easy. Security is not an issue.

Comment: The only thing I can think of and is a cross-computer answer is to print out a string to the user, which works like those passwords from old NES games.

Comment: @MattDiamant - or the trivial option - present the database as a file for download and have the user save it to the network location.

Comment: @enhzflep you beat me to it with 19 secs

Comment: @MattDiamant - yep, I watched yours appear that long after I'd hit enter. :p - great minds and all that...

Comment: Yes this can be done offline despite all the other comments to the contrary. You can even find a sample todo list app along with explanation of how offline apps work  here https://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/offline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue as you... wanted a good notes/task app but couldn't download or install anything.  I made a (very rudimentary) app using the Windows HTA interface, JavaScript, and VBScript.  It's on GitHub (public domain) so you can download it and either use or modify it.  Nothing to install, so you can either download the source files or just copy and paste the code:

https://github.com/freginold/Note

The HTA file provides the inteface (similar to an HTML file) so you can re-code it using HTML if you want.  Because it can use VBScript, it has access to files and can create/modify/store text files.

The app is very basic, but it allows you to create multiple text files and read/modify/delete their contents.  If you run it locally, it's very fast, but over a network it might slow down a bit.

Let me know if you have any questions using it.

Answer (score 1):

look through chrome extensions there are some "notes" extensions.  stickynotes from chrome and firefox should bring back a few extensions/plugins.

see if some of them support bookmarking.  if your work computer you use google chrome, and your other computer you use chrome. and you sign in to chrome with same username/password.  you can "sync your book marks" automatically with google. and then google to other devices automatically.

chrome.storage.sync is limited space of it is either 5 or 10mb?

chrome extension you have a "manifest.json" were you can input "unlimited" to get past the 5mb requirement. for both localstorage and indexeddb if memory serves.

a bit extra coding google.drive if need for storage.

dropbox.com or is it .org?   it has been a couple years i want to say had some auto sync api, and some additional coding. beyond simply, just create a "drive letter"

might suggest find a "file api / library / framework to work with. to help deal with opening/closing/reading various file types. if you plan to code it yourself.

there are some "note/stickynote" librarys / frameworks out there for html/javascript. and you have little menus across bottom, top, left/right of screen and you just move mouse in given direction for a menu to pop out, and you can click on and enter some notes.

==============

if windows computers, you have "one drive" that autosyncs data if you have internet connection. just save to one drive folder. and it takes care of the rest.

==============

if you install google apps (spreadsheet, document) programs. you have access to them online/offline. and if memory serves that have built in google drive accounts into them.

===============

i have not made the script in a very long time. but if you are using a usb stick/drive to move data back and forth.  you can setup a folder on each computer/device.  and place script on the usbdrive. that will duplicate information from folder on pc to usb drive, then usb drive to folder on pc.  then you can use what ever program you want, notepad, wordpad, word, excel, etc... to make what ever you want for todo list in. and other notes.

a bunch of virus / hackers messed things up. with "autorun" and not sure what you need to get "autorun.ini" script to autorun when ever you insert the usb drive anymore. last time i checked, there was a "autorun=batch.bat" within the autorun.ini file, which would run a batch.bat the (bat) extension files are like entering commands into command prompt. but all commands are saved into the .bat file.   if  you can not get autorun to work. just goto file and double click on the batch.bat file to run it.

the script i made up, was for my mom, so she could backup and move here work files around different laptops / desktop computers, and keep backups of the work files.  that was primary doing "backup" but last time she asked me to make a backup for her and double check things. the usb drive was nearly filled to max. and 100's of various documents on it. usb drive was also near end of life and about ready to die.  last time doing i had to buy a a few 8+gig usb drives. to split up all the documents.

she keeps the usb drives, what looks like you might find at a weed/pot type shop. (small little container) with a sliding top on it. so usb drives can be tossed into, and kept from getting sat on / squashed / etc... (hard learned lessons), last time i check she found a plastic container, with flip lid. with some felt inside, looks like it might be some sort of jewelry box. with a rubber band / hair band around it. to keep the lid closed.

=======================

if you have a network. you can just "share folder on network" on each computer. or on a single computer and leave that computer on 24/7 with correct settings of course to wake itself up if network connection comes around.

========================

black friday is coming up hear shortly.  you can get a "wifi router" with a usb or 2 on it. and can insert either usb drive. or a external usb hard drive encloser. and gain access to the drive over internet, and/or local network.  little more costly but... *shrugs*

=======================

if it is simple notes. (text)
not online email readers. but an actual installed email program. say microsoft outlook.  you can setup folders within it, and email yourself, and setup some "rules" if email contains (your email address), and if "subject" contains something move email to this folder within outlook. attach files as needed to the emails.

most online website email pages i think got rid of most of the rules. but i may be mistaken.

======================

usb drive worked for my mom, (not computer smart) she knows drive letter (usb drive) quick and simple. and does not need internet, and in some cases has no internet.

for me, i need a server running 24/7 (server any computer computer running 24/7) with internet access all the time. i need the extra.

but for you. what is it that you really want/need / works for your style of life / doings?

Comment: `5,242,880` The maximum amount (in bytes) of data that can be stored in local storage, as measured by the JSON stringification of every value plus every key's length. This value will be ignored if the extension has the unlimitedStorage permission. Updates that would cause this limit to be exceeded fail immediately and set runtime.lastError.
 - [Source](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#property-local)